# MS Access query too slow

Tags: sql, ms-access

The following query is really slow, anyone could help me speed it up?

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.Item, switch( 
(SELECT COUNT(B1.Item) FROM(SELECT DISTINCT b.Item, Left(b.[Local Instalacao],30) FROM [Lista de objetos] as b) AS B1 WHERE B1.ITEM=M.ITEM) =1,Left(m.[Local Instalacao],30),
(SELECT COUNT(B2.Item) FROM(SELECT DISTINCT b.Item, Left(b.[Local Instalacao],27) FROM [Lista de objetos] as b) AS B2 WHERE B2.ITEM=M.ITEM) =1,Left(m.[Local Instalacao],27),
(SELECT COUNT(B3.Item) FROM(SELECT DISTINCT b.Item, Left(b.[Local Instalacao],24) FROM [Lista de objetos] as b) AS B3 WHERE B3.ITEM=M.ITEM) =1,Left(m.[Local Instalacao],24),
(SELECT COUNT(B4.Item) FROM(SELECT DISTINCT b.Item, Left(b.[Local Instalacao],21) FROM [Lista de objetos] as b) AS B4 WHERE B4.ITEM=M.ITEM) =1,Left(m.[Local Instalacao],21),
(SELECT COUNT(B5.Item) FROM(SELECT DISTINCT b.Item, Left(b.[Local Instalacao],18) FROM [Lista de objetos] as b) AS B5 WHERE B5.ITEM=M.ITEM) =1,Left(m.[Local Instalacao],18),
(SELECT COUNT(B6.Item) FROM(SELECT DISTINCT b.Item, Left(b.[Local Instalacao],15) FROM [Lista de objetos] as b) AS B6 WHERE B6.ITEM=M.ITEM) =1,Left(m.[Local Instalacao],15),
(SELECT COUNT(B7.Item) FROM(SELECT DISTINCT b.Item, Left(b.[Local Instalacao],11) FROM [Lista de objetos] as b) AS B7 WHERE B7.ITEM=M.ITEM) =1,Left(m.[Local Instalacao],11),
(SELECT COUNT(B8.Item) FROM(SELECT DISTINCT b.Item, Left(b.[Local Instalacao],6) FROM [Lista de objetos] as b)  AS B8 WHERE B8.ITEM=M.ITEM) =1,Left(m.[Local Instalacao],6),
true,"") AS localSugerido
FROM [Lista de objetos] AS m
ORDER BY m.ITEM;
```

Is it possible to create an intermediate table and drop it after the query execution ends?

**EDIT**

**Data sample:**

```
+---------+--------------------------+
|  Item   |     Local Instalacao     |
+---------+--------------------------+
| 1549821 | 301095.FEDN.PNN.01.04.01 |
| 1549821 | 301095.FEDN.PNN.01.10.01 |
| 1549821 | 301095.FEDN.PNN.01.46.01 |
| 1549821 | 301095.FEDN.MCB.01.49.01 |
| 1549822 | 301095.FEDN.PNN.01.01    |
| 1549822 | 301095.FEDN.PNN.01.43.01 |
| 1549823 | 301095.FEDN.PNN.03.04.01 |
| 1549823 | 301095.XXXX.PNN.03.37.01 |
+---------+--------------------------+
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**

The common factor for each item

```
+---------+--------------------+
|  Item   |  Local Instalacao  |
+---------+--------------------+
| 1549821 | 301095.FEDN        |
| 1549822 | 301095.FEDN.PNN.01 |
| 1549823 | 301095             |
+---------+--------------------+
```

.

Comment: Yes you should use an intermediate table instead of nested queries. Nested queries are an expensive operation. Next, your switch statements look quite complex for the boolean logic. Is there no way to make it simpler? Thirdly, right this as a stored procedure. If you can implement all three you will see a drastic speed increase

Comment: If you provide sample data and expected result, this can probably be done much easier. See [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271).